# update and select in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure, I am getting an error in the update statement, please help me fix it. Thanks.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserTransac] 
@SponsorId varchar(20),
@UserId varchar(20),
@SponsorName varchar(50),
@Level int=1

AS
BEGIN
  if not exists(select User_Id from UserTransaction)
    insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id,User_Id,Level_No,Sponsor_Name)
    values(@SponsorId,@UserId,@Level,@SponsorName)
  else
    insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id,User_Id,Level_No,Sponsor_Name)
    values(@SponsorId,@UserId,@Level,@SponsorName)

  insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id,User_Id,Level_No,Sponsor_Name)
  values(@SponsorId,@UserId,@Level+1,@SponsorName)

  update UserTransaction 
  set Sponsor_Id=select Sponsor_Id from Register where User_Id=@UserId

END
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: `set Sponsor_Id= Register.Sponsor_Id` I think there are some conditions missing to.

Comment: Have you tried to add "(" and ")" before and after the second select statement? like here: `set Sponsor_Id=` **(** `select Sponsor_Id from Register` **)**

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the answers,but I did not get the desired output. I have explained my question in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712371/update-and-select-in-a-single-querycontinued) post. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Sponsor_Id] = B.[Sponsor_Id]
FROM [UserTransaction] A
INNER JOIN [Register] B ON A.[User_Id] = B.[User_Id]
```

you can also add WHERE clause after INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
update UserTransaction  
set Sponsor_Id = 1 
from Register  
where User_Id = @User_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to put the select within braces. Try this.

```
update UserTransaction set Sponsor_Id=(select Sponsor_Id from Register where User_id=@User_id)
```

Although this will update Sponsor_Id of all the records in UserTransaction. Make sure you use appropriate where clause to update only selected records. Hope this helps.