# update and select in a single query(continued)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I asked the same question in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697981/update-and-select-in-a-single-query?noredirect=1#comment40170384_25697981) but could not explain my requirement properly and hence did not get the desired result. I want to do something like this:

[image]

There are 14 levels in total.Each level can have any number of users. Thank you for the answers provided in the previous post, I tried them but none gave me the desired result.    Please give me an idea how to start with this.
As of now my stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserTransac] 
@SponsorId varchar(20),
@UserId varchar(20),
@SponsorName varchar(50),
@Level int=1

AS
BEGIN
if not exists(select User_Id from UserTransaction)
    insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id,User_Id,Level_No,Sponsor_Name) values(@SponsorId,@UserId,@Level,@SponsorName)
else
    insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id,User_Id,Level_No,Sponsor_Name) values(@SponsorId,@UserId,@Level,@SponsorName)
    insert into UserTransaction(Sponsor_Id,User_Id,Level_No,Sponsor_Name) values(@SponsorId,@UserId,@Level+1,@SponsorName)
```

END

The insert statement goes on till level 14.
After executing the stored procedure my table would look something like this:
[image]

Any useful links or answers where I can get an idea how to go about with this would help. Thank you.

```
UPDATE:
```

[image]

Consider the last two records 11 and 12. For both the records sponsor Id is coming as RL9115.    I want all the levelsto be displayed -ie something like this:
    [image]

```
Hope this is somewhat clear to understand what I want to do
```

Comment: Can you give some input as to how the table is populated above?  Does each new user insert into the table need to insert a level of previous level + 1?  Just trying to understand the requirements a little better to give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks @sumedha.  I'm a little confused if you need help on the insert / select side.  Also, for next time adjusting your original question is probably your best bet instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below should handle getting the desired output with a CTE:

```
DECLARE @TransactionId INT = 11;

WITH levels AS (
    SELECT
        root.Sponsor_Id,
        root.Sponsor_Name,
        root.User_Id,
        root.Level_No
    FROM UserTransaction root
    WHERE root.Transaction_Id = @TransactionId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        s.Sponsor_Id,
        s.Sponsor_Name,
        l.User_Id,
        Level_No = l.Level_No + 1
    FROM UserTransaction s
        INNER JOIN levels l ON l.Sponsor_Id = s.User_Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM levels
ORDER BY Level_No;
```

Validated the answer using [this SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1b42/11/0)

UPDATE: Added Sponsor_Name to result set.

Comment: Actually, I cant understand what you have done. Thanks for answering. I tried the above,I am getting an error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Comment: Can you paste the entire query that you are trying to run?  The keyword "END" isn't in my response, so the syntax error is coming from some other part of the query you are running.

Comment: sorry for late reply.I have done it again,just copy pasted the above in a new query. I am getting the following errors:    Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@TransactionId".
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@TransactionId".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jordan, now I am getting the output as desired. I was getting the previous errors because I am using sql server 2005. I separated the declaration part and assigning part, now its working fine. DECLARE @TransactionId INT    set @TransactionId=11;

Comment: If I want to add sponsor_Name to this query, how should I do it?

Comment: Hey @sumedha - Glad it worked out for you!  I added the Sponsor_Name for you.  See if that is what you had in mind.

Comment: Hi @Jordan Parker, I tried doing the same but it gave me the following errors:  Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UserTransac, Line 13
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "User_Id" of recursive query "levels".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UserTransac, Line 13
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Sponsor_Name" of recursive query "levels".

Comment: Yeah I think I messed up the ordering - too early over here still :)  Try now?

Comment: Yes,got it now,Thanks:) but can you please explain me or give some reference links for the logic part,because I am only copy pasting whatever you did,without understanding anything :(

Comment: also,how do I insert this in the UserTransaction table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60895/discussion-between-sumedha-and-jordan-parker).